# Segmentation fault in aptitude

Tags: lubuntu, aptitude, segmentation-fault

On our 64 bit Lubuntu 14.04 system, `aptitude` has started crashing with a bunch of scrolling errors, ending up with a seg fault.

```
*** Error in `aptitude': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00007fccc4012c50 ***
```

Googling hasn't turned up this error in relation to `aptitude` so I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.  I don't use the program frequently, so I am not sure when the problem started.  I know it was functional when I installed the system.

Comment: what about a reinstall?

Comment: What were you trying to do, can you post the complete log. Thanks

Comment: Just start the program.  Where is the log located?

Comment: @AlexGreg same result after a reinstall.

Comment: Looks like a memory-related error to me. Are you running out of RAM? Or do you have bad RAM cells? You could try booting memtest from GRUB and see if it finds any errors.

Comment: I'll give that a shot as well when I can.

Comment: Ran the memory test from the grub menu.  No errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AlexGreg](https://askubuntu.com/users/222026/alexgreg) suggested a reinstall...at first I did just that with synaptic, with no joy.  But doing a "complete removal" in synaptic, then installing the package, did work.

Answer (score -2):

Ive been having this problem for a few months now, and while its not a solution, Ive worked around it by installing `synaptic` for my package management instead.

If that doesn't work, you can manually install `.deb`'s with `alien`

Comment: Thanks.  Synaptic Package Manager, the Software Center, and `apt` all work fine, so I'm not stuck for ways to manage the system.  I just like to know what's going on.

Comment: `alien` does not install **.deb** (Debian package) files! That is `dpkg`'s job. `alien` is a tool to convert between **.deb**, **.rpm** and other Linux package types.

Comment: `alien -i`, excuse me.

Comment: That might work (I don't know, never used), but you really should use `dpkg -i` to install .deb packages. I don't think it's a good idea to mess around with packages for different distros. And installing simple Debian packages does not require such a specialized tool.